# Beginner trouble updating records PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have read a lot of articles/blogs but I just cannot find what is wrong. I am trying to update the records using `PDO` but when I press send nothing happens, no error, and it does not work.

PHP:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE products SET name = :name WHERE id = :id');
$stmt->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':name', $_POST['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

HTML:

```
<form name="prodForm" class="pure-form pure-form-aligned" method="POST">
  <input name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo $data['nome']; ?>">
  <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $data['id']; ?>">
  <input name="send" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: check for errors on PHP and PDO; you're not doing that.

Comment: Are you receiving an error?

Comment: Can we see the connection

Comment: It doesn't show any error, ive tried PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE etc but the page just refresh itself. This is the connection: `$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=elipdo', 'root', '');`

Comment: It doesn't show any error because it's not configured to. Use `error_reporting`, or use `$stmt->errorInfo()`to see what's wrong here.

Comment: Do you think it doesn't update because I have this going on on the same page? `$read = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = :id');
        $read->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $read->execute();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I found a way to make it work but I don't know why it works like this. I changed the input name to a different one and it worked like magic, I don't know why but if I use:
`value="<?php echo $data['name'];?>" name="name"` it doesn't work but if I do this: 
`value="<?php echo $data['name'];?>" name="anyname"` It works.